# sed to python replace extra delimiters in a

Tags: python, csv, sed

sed 's/\t/_tab_/3g'

I have a sed command that basically replaces all excess tab delimiters in my text document. 
My documents are supposed to be 3 columns, but occasionally there's an extra delimiter. I don't have control over the files.

I use the above command to clean up the document. However all my other operations on these files are in python. Is there a way to do the above sed command in python?

sample input:

```
Column1   Column2         Column3
James     1,203.33        comment1
Mike      -3,434.09       testing testing 123
Sarah     1,343,342.23    there   here
```

sample output:

```
Column1   Column2         Column3
James     1,203.33        comment1
Mike      -3,434.09       testing_tab_testing_tab_123
Sarah     1,343,342.23    there_tab_here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may read the file line by line, split with tab, and if there are more than 3 items, join the items after the 3rd one with `_tab_`:

```
lines = []
with open('inputfile.txt', 'r') as fr:
    for line in fr:
        split = line.split('\t')
        if len(split) > 3:
            tmp = split[:2]                      # Slice the first two items
            tmp.append("_tab_".join(split[2:]))  # Append the rest joined with _tab_
            lines.append("\t".join(tmp))         # Use the updated line
        else:
            lines.append(line)                   # Else, put the line as is
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ZD81nF)

The `lines` variable will contain something like

```
Mike    -3,434.09   testing_tab_testing_tab_123
Mike    -3,434.09   testing_tab_256
No  operation   here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.system("sed -i 's/\t/_tab_/3g' " + file_path)
```

Does this work? Please notice that there is a **-i** argument for the above sed command, which is used to modify the input file inplace.

Comment: I'm on windows and am not sure how I would add sed to path. Using cygwin if that helps. To be honest i'd really just prefer to have everything in a python program if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can mimic the `sed` behavior in python:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'\t')
string = 'Mike\t3,434.09\ttesting\ttesting\t123'
replacement = '_tab_'
count = -1
spans = []
start = 2 # Starting index of matches to replace (0 based)
for match in re.finditer(pattern, string):
    count += 1
    if count >= start:
        spans.append(match.span())
spans.reverse()
new_str = string
for sp in spans:
     new_str = new_str[0:sp[0]] + replacement + new_str[sp[1]:]
```

And now `new_str` is `'Mike\t3,434.09\ttesting_tab_testing_tab_123'`.

You can wrap it in a function and repeat for every line.
However, note that this GNU sed behavior isn't standard:

> 'NUMBER'
>        Only replace the NUMBERth match of the REGEXP.
>
> ```
>  interaction in 's' command Note: the POSIX standard does not
>  specify what should happen when you mix the 'g' and NUMBER
>  modifiers, and currently there is no widely agreed upon meaning
>  across 'sed' implementations.  For GNU 'sed', the interaction is
>  defined to be: ignore matches before the NUMBERth, and then match
>  and replace all matches from the NUMBERth on.
> ```